# Google Chrome Application using Google Fonts

Tags: css, fonts, google-chrome-app

I am trying to include the link stylesheet to use a font from Google fonts. I've tried the Web Font Loader and the actual link stylesheet and yet I keep getting the CSP error.

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"style-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource: 'unsafe-inline'".
```

This is my CSP in my `manifest.json`

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self';",
```

Now since I haven't read the entire Documentation on CSP's because it seems to get left and right when I'm trying to read this maybe someone could enlighten me how this works, what I need to get my stylesheet to work.

Another Method I've tried:

```
 load({
    method:"GET",
    url:"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600"
 },function(data){
   var style = document.createElement('style');
   var head = document.head;
   style.innerHTML = data.responseText;
   head.insertBefore(style, head.firstChild);
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reason even the load won't work, so I did some more research and to use a Google Fonts in a Chrome App use the import method instead of standard or javascript.

EX:

**stylesheet**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

And everything works A Ok just like that!